# marshalling C and C#

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have the following marshalling code in my project. I have few questions on this.

```
[DllImport=(Core.dll, SetLastError=true, EntryPoint="CoreCreate", CharSet="CharSet.Ansi", CallingConvention="CallingConvention.Cdecl")]
internal static extern uint CoreCreate(ref IntPtr core);
```

1. Why **'internal static extern'** is required? Is this compulsory? Why this is used?
2. What is **SetLastError**?

> ```
> [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
> internal struct Channel
> {
> internal byte LogicalChannel;
> }
> ```

Why **LayoutKind.Sequential**?

Comment: i think this article would help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This seems to be more than one question and should probably be created as separate posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why 'internal static extern' is required?

The `internal` modifier just set visibility of your method. It's not required to be `internal` so you can declare the method `private` or `public` as you need and as you would do with any other *standard* method.

The `static` modifier is required because it's not an instance method and that method *doesn't know* any class (it hasn't a `this` pointer).

Finally `extern` is required to inform the compiler that the method isn't implemented here but in another place (and you'll specify where using attributes). Evey `extern` method must be declared `static` too (because it's a simple function call without any knowledge about objects).

> What is SetLastError?

It indicates that method may change the thread's last-error code value. See the [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for details about this. If the called function will change this value then it's a good thing to set `SetLastError` to `true`, from MSDN:

> The runtime marshaler calls GetLastError and **caches the value returned to prevent it from being overwritten by other API calls**. You can retrieve the error code by calling GetLastWin32Error.

In short it saves the value returned by GetLastError() to an internal cache so any other call to system API (even internal to others framework functions) won't overwrite that value.

> Why LayoutKind.Sequential?

Class layout in .NET isn't required to be sequential in memory (sequential = if `A` is declared before `B` then memory layout has `A` before `B`). This is not true in C where the declaration order matters (declaration is used by the compiler to understand the layout, in memory, of raw data). If you have to interop with C functions then you have to be sure about the layout of the data you pass them. This is how `LayoutKind.Sequential` works: it instructs the compiler to respect the declaration sequential order for data in the `struct`. This is not the only option to interop with unmanaged world, you can even explicitly set the offset (from structure beginning) of each field (see LayoutKind.Explicit).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just a few comments:
"internal static" is one thing and "extern" is another thing needed when calling external dll's.
SetLastError or GetLastError is methods we used a lot in the "old" days to get error messages from windows about the latest handling.
LayoutKind.Sequential is a way to inform the compiler to layout the struct in a specified way - you may need to do this if marchalling to other systems.

Comment: Perhaps post it as a comment instead of an answer then?

Comment: So, it must be a comment. Besides, a pair `static extern` is a requirement for `DllImport`. Hence, `internal` is one thing, and `static extern` is another thing.

Comment: Easy guys - it seems i'm not allowed to add comments to questions yet !!